# how to see the imported pfx file on android

Tags: android, security, certificate, pfx

1. I created a customized certificate file (123.pfx)
2. I download 123.pfx to my PC, and connect to my android device with USB cable.
3. I copy the 123.pfx to the root of my android device.
4. I finished the installation process of 123.pfx and get the successfully installed message on my android device.
5. but why I still can't see the 123.pfx listed in "Trusted credentials" (Both for SYSTEM and USER panel)?